# My DbSet<Entity> won't update when trying from Unit Testing (MSTest) code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, mstest, dbcontext

I am unit testing my MVC application. One of the tests is validating if my controller is correctly returning data for provided id.

To Unit test it, I want to add data from my [TestMethod] to the Context.DBSet and then call my Controller method and validate its output.

However, my added record isn't reflected inside the Context.DBSet object.

Below is the code that I currently have.

```
    ///for purpose of unit testing, there is no underlying database
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new ApplicationDbContextInitializer());
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
        public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class ApplicationDbContextInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            InitializeBooks(context);
            InitializeCustomers(context);
            base.Seed(context);
        }
    }
    //for brevity, i haven't posted the InitializeBooks & InitializeCustomers()
    //these methods create Book and Customer objects
    //and do context.Book.Add(objBook) and context.Customer.Add(objCustomer)
```

My Controller class has DbContext object which I use in my MS Test

```
    public class CustomersController : Controller
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        ///other methods exist too
    }
```

Finally my MSTest

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestCustomerIDReplacedCorrectly()
{
    var objCtrl = new CustomersController();
    Customer objCust = new Customer()
    {
        Name = "Foo Bar",
        Address = "Hello World",
    };

    Console.WriteLine(objCtrl.db.Customers.Count()) //returns 4 correctly
    objCtrl.db.Customers.Add(objCust);
    Console.WriteLine(objCtrl.db.Customers.Count()) //still returns 4!? it should return 5

    ///calls are given to controller method
    ///to fetch ViewResult and ViewBag
    ///to validate if it is processing the
    ///instance put inside the objCtrl.db.Customers
}
```

I see that the added customer is not reflected inside by Customer's DbContext object, thus even my actual controller method which I'm supposed to validate, doesn't reflect my desired behavior either. How do I ensure that my `objCust` is added to `objCtrl.db.Customers.Add`

Here is the InitializeCustomers() code which is called for seeding

```
        private void InitializeCustomers(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            Customer cust1 = new Customer()
            {
                Name = "James Butt",
                Address = "6649 N Blue Gum St",
                Contact = "50-621 8927",
                NationalID = "12312312312"
            };

            Customer cust2 = new Customer()
            {
                Name = "Josephine Darakjy",
                Address = "Chanay, Jeffrey A Esq",
                Contact = "81-292 9840",
                NationalID = "123123124"
            };

            Customer cust3 = new Customer()
            {
                Name = "Art Venere",
                Address = "Chemel, James L Cpa",
                Contact = "85-636 8749",
                NationalID = "123123456"
            };


            Customer cust4 = new Customer()
            {
                Name = "Lenna Paprocki",
                Address = "Feltz Printing Service",
                Contact = "90-385 4412",
                NationalID = "32165498712"
            };

            context.Customers.Add(cust1);
            context.Customers.Add(cust2);
            context.Customers.Add(cust3);
            context.Customers.Add(cust4);

        }
```

Comment: do your `InitializeBooks` and `InitializeCustomers` methods work as expected? if so, please post at least one of them

Comment: yes they seed the data correctly, thus when i do `Count()` in my `[TestMethod()]`, they reflect 4 correctly
added the code at the end

Comment: You aren't actually unit testing your controller. You are testing your database. In your test you aren't calling a single method on your controller, just accessing the publicly facing `db` property and working with the database directly. If that's what you really want to do that is fine, but at that point you are testing EF which doesn't serve any real purpose. 

For this to be a unit test of the controller, you need to actually test a controller method and at that point your database should be mocked out entirely and you only test if behaviors occur that should occur.

Comment: call `SaveChanges()` after `Add` function

Comment: I had kept my MSTest intentionally short because the question was getting very long. The test is actually hitting the controller method to validate if the object I add in my DB object is processed according to the BusinessRules. I check the ViewResult and ViewBag objects returned by this method

Comment: The SaveChanges() function is doing my job. However, I am hesitant to use it because I do not want to persist the values to DB. I want to have all my objects only in memory so that once my test session is over, I don't have any overhead of cleaning up the DB.
Additoinally, we are planning this MSTests to be integrated in the Testing Phase of our CI/CD with no DB on the server. That is the reason I am so much hesitating to use a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `objCtrl.db.SaveChanges();` for the object to be added to the `DbSet`. Currently, you aren't doing so and `objCtrl.db.Customers.Count()` queries the database for the count of objects **currently stored** in the database. Since you haven't called `SaveChanges` yet, you're object has not been written to the database and will not be included in the `.Count()` method call.

It's common to use a separate db which is only used for testing and seeded with the needed data (if any is needed) to test. Often, you'll see each test wrapped in a transaction so that you can perform the needed test, validate data, then rollback all of the operations so the database is back at it's starting state for each test

Comment: how does the value seed without the DB then, I am eyeing rite now on the base.Seed() as see in the `ApplicationDbContextInitializer `, somehow, if i could get my hands on that, I would attempt to call the `Seed(dbObject)`

Comment: @AvdhutVaidya that seems like a very roundabout way to fix your issue. I'm guessing (since it's not posted) the `Seed` method in your `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` class calls `.SaveChanges` within itself somewhere... all you need to do to correct your issue is call `.SaveChanges` in your test method to resolve the issue

Comment: I differ from this thought a little bit; that's because currently `Seed()` is called and there is no DB connection to my application. `.SaveChanges()` would just crash the program then.

Comment: I do not have access to `Seed()`, it is only inherited. Also, I have to use either `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` or `DropCreateAlways` or `DropCreateIfModelChanges` because EF needs me to write it.

Comment: GregH, my issue is probably resolved I see, I attempted `.SaveChanges()` and it didn't give me error. This is surprising. I have been receiving exception on `.SaveChanges()` since yesterday, but I didn't note what exception. To put that exception here, I reran my test with `.SaveChanges()` and it surprising returned additional record!!
Let me check once again pl.

Comment: @AvdhutVaidya yes, there's no valid reason for .SaveChanges to crash your app in this scenario unless you've made a mistake elsewhere. Also, check your connection string (most commonly in the web.config) to see where your database is that you're using (you said you're not using one but I can pretty well guarantee you that's not true.. even if it's an in memory database, it's still a database). Glad I could help!

Comment: OK, I guess, I messed up some configuration somewhere and the `.SaveChanges()` is working incorrectly. When I re-ran my test for confirming the second time that `SaveChanges()` still works, it showed me the data I saved in my earlier test run. It shouldn't because there is no where I am persisting it. I need to check it and I will come back here

Comment: @AvdhutVaidya I think you're lacking some understanding about EntityFramework. You're 100% definitely persisting the data somewhere- it doesn't magically get stored by itself and it seems like SaveChanges is working exactly as expected- it successfully saved data to your database. Again, to see the name and location of your database, find the connection string that you're using for your `ApplicationDbContext`... the vast majority of the time this is stored in the web.config file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202747/discussion-between-avdhut-vaidya-and-gregh).